# align div right of a left nav and not below - bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using this code snippet: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-sidebar-menu-hover-effect-66945518 and cant figure out how to get content to go to the right of nav. I am sure its something simple I am missing with bootstrap5's changes.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 250px;"> <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none"> <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"> </svg> <span class="fs-4">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="ms-2">Home</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="ms-2">Dashboard</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-first-order"></i><span class="ms-2">My Orders</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="ms-2">Settings</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i><span class="ms-2">Bookmarks</span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2"> <strong> John W </strong> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if what you have is the "left nav" and you want to put content to the right, you can use the [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width) classes and place it inside a `.container > .row > .col` and then add another sibling `.col` to hold the content.

Or you can use [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink), and wrap it in a `div.d-flex` and add a sibling `.flex-grow-1` to hold the content (this will expand to fill remaining space to the right) as is the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 250px;">
    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none"> <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"> </svg> <span class="fs-4">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="ms-2">Home</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="ms-2">Dashboard</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-first-order"></i><span class="ms-2">My Orders</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="ms-2">Settings</span> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i><span class="ms-2">Bookmarks</span> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2"> <strong> John W </strong> </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow-1 p-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Yup</h1>
        <p>
          Stuff on the right.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to put on your

tags (or even , if you don't want aling the ) the bootstrap class "text-end".

You can find more about the text-alignment in [bootstrap using the framework documentation!](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 250px;"> <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none"> <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"> </svg> <span class="fs-4">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
        <li class="nav-item text-end"> <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="ms-2">Home</span> </a> </li>
        <li class="text-end"> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="ms-2">Dashboard</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-first-order"></i><span class="ms-2">My Orders</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="ms-2">Settings</span> </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white"> <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i><span class="ms-2">Bookmarks</span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle me-2"> <strong> John W </strong> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, snippets are for working code examples. Notice how I include the css and js in my snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815806/6127393 this way it will run/render as expected with BS framework loaded when you click "Run code snippet". Non-running examples should utilize a simple code block instead.